# Al cargar imágenes desde un json en firebase, estas no se muestran

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase

Tengo hecho el deploy de firebase de mi aplicación de react. Donde se deberían ver las imágenes del producto no se ven... Si bien están bien cargadas ya que mientras en la dev se pueden ver, en el deploy no. Las imágenes están cargadas mediante un map de un JSON en la carpeta public: `"image": "../public/images/n3.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu `firebase.json` está configurado con public como directorio base, es decir asi:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}
```

Entonces desde tu aplicación deberias leer los archivos teniendo en cuenta que public es tu directorio base. Entonces las imagenes en este caso estarian ubicadas en `"image": "../images/n3.jpg"`